# assigning an item in a list using a function to get the desired address

Tags: python, list, pointers, variable-assignment

## how can I return the address of the value in the list I wish to change?

I can change a value in a list in this manner:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[0] = 0
```

but how can I change a value that a helper function choose?

```
helper = lambda x: x[0]
a = [1, 2, 3]
helper(a) = 0
```

will produce a runtime error type syntax error
(because python interpret it like 1 = 0)

my question is how can I build a function that chooses the index for me?

## functions that return only the index are not helpful:

example:

```
helper = lambda x: 0
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[helper(a)] = 0
```

will not solve the problem for (for example) 2d lists:

```
helper_1 = lambda x: 0, 0
a = [[1, 2, 3]]
a[helper(a)[0]][helper(a)[1]] = 0
```

as you can see this makes the code very ugly very fast.

I will provide two simple examples for this issue:

## first example code, 1d list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
for x in lst:
    x *= 2
# will not change the list
```

if there were pointers:

```
for &x in lst:
    *x *= 2
```

## second example code, 2d list:

```
def rotate_90(image, direction):
    rows, columns = len(image), len(image[0])
    rotated = empty_2d(columns, rows) # allocate 2d list
    
    rotated_place = lambda row, col: rotated[col][-1- row] \
                     if direction =='R' else \
                    lambda row, col: rotated[-1-col][row]
        
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(columns):
            rotated_place(row, col) = image[row][col] # error
            
    return rotated
# will produce an error
```

if there were pointers:

```
def rotate_90(image, direction):
    rows, columns = len(image), len(image[0])
    rotated = empty_2d(columns, rows) # aloccate memory
    
    rotated_place = lambda row, col: &rotated[col][-1- row] \
                     if direction =='R' else \
                    lambda row, col: &rotated[-1-col][row]
        
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(columns):
            *rotated_place(row, col) = image[row][col]
            
    return rotated
```

Comment: why cant you set the element in the list in the helper function itself? Isnt that simpler.

Comment: yes, for some applications, but for others it will not help.
for example: 
def foo(a): return a[0].

for (...) if (?) {foo(a) = 1} else {print(foo(a))}

Comment: Please give an example of when @AlbinPaul's suggestion won't work for you and also please qualify what you mean by *address* in this context

Comment: I edited my comments, its hard to write a function is a line. is the example clear?

Comment: Its clear to me. But unfortunately its not c++. we cant get a pointer to an integer variable behaviour.

Comment: Your best bet is to get the indexes from foo and set them. Else we need to use class objects which are passed by reference or something along those lines.

Comment: but for 2d lists returning an index will be very ugly. I think its very weird that there isn't a way to do this. everybody encounters this problem even in simple for loop -  when we have to do: {for I in range(len(lst)): lst[I] *= 2} instead of {for I in lst: I *= 2}

Comment: [An idea](https://tio.run/##hZJNbsMgEIX3PsUsTcUibfqTROoVqqpbhBByxq4lDBbgRt306i5gq4ZkURYWgve@eTN4/PafRu8Po53nM7ZgjZcexXFX94PskJwqCMuai6PQGDUN2sErKNTrPd32bMfJqo6Mc9Ax9mY0crhLBGiNBQG9Bit1h/XKIzy50qdR0jn4WADvSja4BIgrxhOiQ997HISoHaqWRjDZNDnjUh5vCHeFCDkofEk1Ibm1ZA2xIOTsJ1TkobdkKOQW/WR1rFwXgxBjbCRY8r6CJGniTAJxm0qcVJYj3oe6t1MroxalWIyY0oaiy9v8nRSuKou9EqoqGdLj3VN4oLDnFNgjhScKz3H7QuFA4ch5lWVPpiXSaHvtYxuhw2VPNuj1//UvY55/AQ) that lets you write `rotated_place[row][col] = image[row][col]` (not really what you're asking for, I know, but still).

Comment: [Simplified](https://tio.run/##hZLBSsQwEIbvfYo5tpLD6qrogq8g4jWEELrZtZAmJUkVL756nZm0tK6Ccwgh88@f7w8ZPvNb8PuHIU7T0Z4ghmyy1Y@7uuvN2TaHCrBi@EgC2uDG3id4Amf93BfrXu5UM6vJ44g6KZ@Dtwqu2AFOIYKGzkM0/mzr2a9RPMVL60xK8FoMXpxpbQGgIjytk81dtr3WdbLuJMhYo5GAd@PGhXcpbDI2osy6izbfI/FcyS9UKBSyzzaHHogDO1usuqlYQ5FwcA1FQTcU1CeAX6EPf5GUq@SCTTjlaYmNMX9MFUqbx@gXh6riAX77awE3AvZKgLwVcCfgXqlqA8zKwjHEzmdix1hl36xOl3/iX49p@gY) allowing `rotated_place[row, col] = image[row][col]`.

Comment: @gilaharoni There is pointers inside the ctypes module since it is a wrapper around c.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#pointers. If you use this it would be a bit too complicated for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a bit for clarity, you want this to print `[42, 2, 3]`:

```
first = ...

a = [1, 2, 3]
first(a) = 42

print(a)
```

You can make it work with `first[a]` instead of `first(a)`:

```
class First:
    def __setitem__(_, lst, value):
        lst[0] = value
first = First()

a = [1, 2, 3]
first[a] = 42

print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxCgIxEET7/YotE0ihdxYi2PoT4VgWzWEgniG7J/j1MTGvm5nH5K8@39t8zqXWe2IRvMUiegFsPMKKRBI0angRGXKYRB1@OO3BDqfTSn9Y8DoGWPtDS/8nYwG4BX90ODmclzF77v5pAsglbmrY1voD)